# Trying to copy a range from one sheet and paste it to the next empty cell in a column on another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a range from one sheet `("H2:H200")` or can be `Range("H2").End(xlDown)` (neither of these works) and paste it to the next empty cell on another cell. (basically putting two columns under each other). I have the following code, but I get "Worksheet Object Failed" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Mergescript()
Dim ssaw_p As Worksheet
Dim oqs As Worksheet

Set ssaw_p = Sheets("SSAW_EXPORT")
Set oqs = Sheets("SQL_IMPORT")

ssaw_p.Range("H2:H200").Copy Destination:=oqs.Range("G").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't this select the next empty cell in column G? As in a single cell, oqs.Range("G").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: What is in G? Are you trying to go beyond the end of the sheet? I would also use a full cell reference e.g. G2.

Comment: there's a random amount of filled cells in G, so I'd need to paste stuff from another sheet after the filled cells

Comment: In addition to my comment about the full cell reference you could avoid all this and come up from bottom of sheet as in my answer below. Avoids issue of trying to go off the sheet with offset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the oqs.range,  is not correct try this :

```
ssaw_p.Range("H2:H200").Copy Destination:=oqs.Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

this will copy your ssaw range after the first empty cell in column G

Comment: yep this one did the trick, just had to change ("G") to ("G1"), thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Mergescript()
Dim ssaw_p As Worksheet
Dim oqs As Worksheet

Set ssaw_p = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SSAW_EXPORT")
Set oqs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SQL_IMPORT")

With ssaw_p
    .Range("H2:H200").Copy Destination:=oqs.Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
End With

End Sub
```

this works

Answer (score 2):

To avoid trying to go off the end of the sheet (if nothing in G ) use the following.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Mergescript()
    Dim ssaw_p As Worksheet
    Dim oqs As Worksheet

    Set ssaw_p = Sheets("SSAW_EXPORT")
    Set oqs = Sheets("SQL_IMPORT")

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim nextRow As Long

    With oqs

      lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    If lastRow = 1 Then
        nextRow = 1
    Else
       nextRow = lastRow + 1
    End If

     ssaw_p.Range("H2:H200").Copy Destination:=oqs.Range("G" & nextRow)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is by far the most comprehensive answer, but I just swapped "G" for "G1" going by h2so4's recommendation. I am copying around 20 columns over so opening a new sub for each would be a pain haha

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
ssaw_p.Range("H2:H" & Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row).Copy oqs.Range("G" & oqs.Range("G2").End(xlDown).Row + 1)
```

This code will always copy all data in sheet EXPORT Range H2: to last cell in Column H and paste it into the first blank column found in column G on sheet IMPORT